# test-verify goal doesn't work with maven-soapui-extension-plugin

Tags: maven, soapui

I see the following error when I try to run SoapUI Projects

Failed to execute goal com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui:maven-soapui-extension-plugin:4.6.4.2:test-verify (test-verify) on project TestProjects: SoapUI Test(s) failed: see logs and/or check the printReport (if necessary, set the option to true) -> [Help 1]

Child Pom File:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>Tutor</groupId>
    <artifactId>TutorOnTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <relativePath>..</relativePath>
</parent>
<artifactId>TestProjects</artifactId>
<name>TestProjects</name>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository</id>
        <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-soapui-extension-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.4.2</version>
             <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>ojdbc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                    <version>11.1.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>run-Tests</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectFiles>
                            <scan>
                                <baseDirectory>${basedir}</baseDirectory>
                                <includes>
                                  <include>**/*-soapui-project.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                            </scan>
                        </projectFiles>
                        <projectProperties>
                            <value>url=http://localhost:8080</value>
                        </projectProperties>
                          <useOutputFolderPerProject>true</useOutputFolderPerProject>
                        <testFailIgnore>true</testFailIgnore>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-verify</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>test-verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <printReport>true</printReport>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: ... and what are the logs telling?

Comment: Which logs are you talking about? Are you asking for the full stack trace of this error?

Comment: The Maven logs of the build yes. Thet should contain more information.